# WinAPI mouse click does not work properly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mouse

I am creating program in C++ (Windows 7 ), that controls one specific window by reading its screen and sending back mouse signals (only left-clicks). I am using WinAPI obviously. Problem is with the mouse signals. My target is to send mouse events independently on actual cursor position. (i.e. it can run on "the background" and the window does not have to be visible).

I tried the obvious solution using SendMessage (or PostMessage):

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP  , MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
```

I think the commands work fine but there is some problem with how the application process the click events. It seems it does not take into account the parameters x,y and instead when `WM_LBUTTONUP` is called, it asks OS where the cursor is and make the click on that location. So in the end the click occurs always on the location of cursor (if it is inside the window).

I also tried to send `WM_MOUSEMOVE` event before `WM_LBUTTONUP` but it didn't help.

This behavior is really strange, and I fully blame the application not WinAPI. Any ideas how to solve this? Can I maybe somehow trick the window so it thinks that cursor is elsewhere?

Comment: _"Any ideas how to solve this?"_ - Well if your target application is retrieving the current mouse position instead of using the coordinates passed with the message you need to fix the target application.

Comment: Try [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Why are people obsessed with the idea, that faking input would be a good option to automate a UI, instead of going for the straight forward solution, and use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx)? It's there for a reason. @milevyo: `SendInput` requires, that the application is visible, the foreground window, and the desired location not obscured by any other window. No need to try.

Comment: @IInspectable, agree, but i have never seen a working example. can you post one?

Comment: @milevyo Really, you cannot find an example of UI Automation by websearch?

Comment: @IInspectable, sorry, i didn't see this `the window does not have to be visible` that, that realy makes a big change.  that is true neither sendinput nor WM_ mouse events will work. the only way left are as you mentioned `UI Automation` or if the OP is clicking on a known control then `WM_COMMAND+ Ctrl ID` is easier. one up from me :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only thing you need then [use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) `SendInput`  with the `MOUSEINPUT` structure.

If you want to understand why then read on. What you are doing does not work because mouse messages are special. They are not regular messages that arrive and wait for you in the message queue. They are synthesized on demand when you call `GetMessage` and therefore they get their data from a secret, hidden place . In fact, generally speaking input messages are treated differently than posted messages. [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=42343) is [some](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=4203) [reading](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=35513) material.

Comment: `SendInput` generates input the same way a hardware driver would. Since you cannot click on an invisible window with a physical mouse (a requirement of the question), neither can input generated by a call to `SendInput`. So that's not an option. Your description about input messages is not accurate either. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`/`UP` messages are posted to the input queue. `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages are generated on demand.

Comment: @IInspectable : You have to activate the window. I was not solving that problem. You don't want to inject input if the window is not active, regardless of method. Ever. For example restoring the window might give a window of a different size or different window contents.  The question is about x and y and my answer is the reason.

Comment: You don't have to activate the window. You have to pick the right tool for the job. To automate a UI, [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) is the right tool.